# Attempting to instantiate an object of an abstract class, is this a Compilation error or Syntax error?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, syntax-error, abstract-class, abstract

When attempting to instantiate an abstract class, what type of error is this? 
Compilation or Syntax error?

Comment: Syntax errors *are* a kind of compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

It is a compilation error. This is because you are trying to create an instance of an abstract class at any point.

The reason why this is not possible is very simple. The sense of an abstract class is that it contains method declarations that are not yet implemented. The implementation is then done in the child classes which inherit from this abstract class. So assuming you have an abstract class like:

```
abstract class Vehicle {

    abstract void move();

}
```

And also assuming it would be possible to instantiate a Vehicle like `Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle()`. Which code should be executed when you call `vehicle.move()`?

To instantiate a `Vehicle` you would have to create a concrete class which inherits from `Vehicle` and then overrides the `move` function. Like:

```
class Car extends Vehicle {

     @Override
     void move() { 
         System.out.println("brum brum....");
     }
}
```